# Bullet Physics StepSimulation really slow when smaller TriangleMeshShape is inside bigger BoxShape

Tags: performance, bullet-physics

I observed that bullet physics StepSimulation is very very slow when a rigidbody with a TriangleMeshShape is fully inside a rigidbody with a simple BoxShape. I noticed that when I move the trianglemeshshape object a bit out of the boxshape my simulation started to run as fast as usual. How can i improve the performance for thats cenario? At some point in my simulation I have to test for all trianglemeshshapes are fully inside a boundingbox. So far i have to do the test on demand and cant just keep the boxshape in the simulation all the time.

I tried using ghostobjects but that didnt help to improve the performance. I assume that the problem lies with the inetrnal working of bullet physics and how the DynamicsWorld performs the collision testing.

Does anyone have an idea how to improve performance for many small trianglemeshShapes inside one big boxshape? all my shapes are kinematic.

Comment: I have only little experience with bullet physics. I haven't heard of testing that an object is _inside_ another, only checking when an object is outside. So what if you used 6 boxes to mimic the single box and you checked if your mesh is outside of each of those?

Comment: I thought about splitting up into 6 outside boxes but that wouldn't help me either, because I do allow objects outside of the box at times. It's a placement application with a working area and at the end a test if all objects are inside. I just don't want to bother adding a rigidbody and removing it at the end. But I guess I have to.

Comment: Usually I'd solve this by doing 6 plane checks. No plane colliders, just testing with 6 normal vectors and offsets. I don't know the Bullet API well enough to identify whether it has convenience methods for this though.